# Get clicked cell value in DevExpress DataGrid using WPF

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, wpf-4.0

I have a DevExpress DataGrid in wpf apllication and it will contain two columns my problem is that I want to get particular clicked cell value in DevExpress DataGrid.

Please anybody help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify clicked [column](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridViewInfoGridHitInfo_Columntopic) and [row handle](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridViewInfoGridHitInfo_RowHandletopic) using the hit-information returned by the [GridView.CalcHitInfo()](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CalcHitInfotopic) method:

```
GridHitInfo hitInfo = gridView1.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
if(hitInfo.InRowCell){
    object value = View.GetRowCellValue(hitInfo.RowHandle, hitInfo.Column);
    //...
}
```

Related help-article: [Hit Information Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument770)
Related How-To: [Identify the Grid's Element Located Under the Mouse Cursor](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3052)

Comment: can you help me for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224279/how-to-get-all-grid-cell-values-on-key-press-on-cell-editing-using-devepxress-gr

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE I'm sorry but I believe, it is better to use DevExpress Support to find an appropriate solution in this specific scenario...